# How to show subcategory image in opencart

Tags: opencart

I have added the extension but getting an error of model not found

Notice: Error: Could not load model D:\xampp\htdocs\youthiapa/admin/model/extension/module.php! in D:\xampp\htdocs\youthiapa\system\modification\system\engine\loader.php on line 24

Comment: Which extension are you using? I've used [Subcategorie Images](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=22194&filter_search=refine%20categories) with no issues.

Comment: i used this extension for showing subcategory with image  https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=24158   Subcategory Image

Comment: You not place the files in proper way or your version not comparable with your opencart version.